# How to Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 in dual boot mode with windows 7?

Tags: updates

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7. I gave Ubuntu 30gb disk space. Now how can I update Ubuntu to 15.04?
My laptop is Dell Vostro 1014.
Will up-gradation reduce significant amount of disk space?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot from the Install DVD, select install ubuntu, and there should be an option to upgrade to 15.04.  This should not drastically impact disk space (no more than a few hundred MB).